# Cannot Boot to USB with PCChips A13G+ Motherboard

Tags: boot, bios

Basically, I want to install a new OS on an old computer I built a while back. It doesn't have a CD drive. I made a Live USB stick using unetbootin and my main computer has no issues booting to it.

In the BIOS, I set First boot device to "Removable", then CDROM, then Hard Disk. I previously tried disabling options 2 and 3, and just set booting to removable but no luck with that either.

In the BIOS, there are also areas to choose boot priority within a category. So under "Removable Device Priority" it shows the USB drive and i have it listed as first. Under "Hard Disk Boot Priority" it only has my hard drive listed, and not the USB drive, as I thought it should.

The computer has never had a CDROM drive so I know it booted from a USB once, but i'm stumped. Here is a link to the motherboard's manual in case it helps:
http://download.ecsusa.com/dlfilepcc/manual/A13G_A13G+_30a.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the device descriptors on your USB stick, and whether its formatted with or without a partition table, it may be reported as removable or a fixed disk.  Many old BIOSes may only be compatible with one particular scheme.

Comment: so how do i find out which formatting I need?